# SOQL inside nested for loop

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits

I'm displaying the accounts name those have cases attached in it. Accounts with no cases won't be displayed here. Unfortunately I'm facing 50001 error since I'm doing SOQL inside a for loop. But I'm supposed to loop through the case to display the result.
This is my code.

```
Integer OffSt = 0;
Integer lmt = 40000;
Set<Id> stContactIds = new Set<Id>();

Integer casesCount = [
    SELECT Id, ContactId, AccountId
    FROM Case
    WHERE (
        RecordType.Name = 'Support Case' OR
        RecordType.Name = 'CAE Support Case' OR 
        RecordType.Name = 'L2 Case' OR 
        RecordType.Name = 'Atmel Classic')
].size();

if (casesCount > 0) {
    for(offSt= 0; offst < casesCount; offst+=lmt) {
        for(Case cas : [
            SELECT Id,ContactId,AccountId 
            FROM Case 
            WHERE (
                RecordType.Name = 'Support Case' OR 
                RecordType.Name = 'CAE Support Case' OR 
                RecordType.Name = 'L2 Case' OR 
                RecordType.Name = 'Atmel Classic')
            ]
        ){
            stContactIds.add(cas.AccountId);    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since you have plenty of answers I'm just gonna give you a few notes I noticed noone else posted. You should use an `IN` clause `WHERE RecordType.Name IN ('Support Case','CAE Support Case','L2 Case','Atmel Classic')` instead of several `OR`s. Also when you post code try to format it in a way to where there is no horizontal scroll bar (I reformatted your code to provide an example). Finally, what's your use case? there's probably a better way to achieve it. Sometimes the problems are architectural in nature.

Answer (score 2):

> Unfortunately I'm facing 50001 error since I'm doing SOQL inside a for
>   loop.

As others have pointed out, you have done a SOQL query in for loop which is giving you that error.

You don't need to execute that same query twice. 
Once you run the query and get the data in a list, you can use size() to get the number of records returned by that query.

e.g.

```
List<Account> accountList = [
    SELECT Id, Name 
    FROM Account 
    WHERE Id In (
        SELECT AccountId 
        FROM Case
        WHERE (
            RecordType.Name = 'Support Case' OR 
            RecordType.Name = 'CAE Support Case' OR 
            RecordType.Name = 'L2 Case' OR
            RecordType.Name = 'Atmel Classic'
        )
    )
];

System.debug('number of records in accountList : ' + accountList.size());
```

Having said that, you also don't need that second for loop. And as Account and Case are related, we can get AccountId and Account Name in a single query.

```
Set<Id> stContactIds = new Set<Id>();
List<String> stContactNames = new List<String>();

for (Account acc :[
    SELECT Id, Name 
    FROM Account 
    WHERE Id In (
        SELECT AccountId FROM Case
        WHERE (
            RecordType.Name = 'Support Case' OR 
            RecordType.Name = 'CAE Support Case' OR 
            RecordType.Name = 'L2 Case' OR 
            RecordType.Name = 'Atmel Classic'
        )
    )
]) {
    stContactIds.add(acc.Id);       // Add AccountId to Set of Ids
    stContactNames.add(acc.Name);   // Add Account Name to list
}
```

As you might have noticed, I have changed the queries. If you want to use the query that you have written in your example, 
you will have to add another condition to check if AccountId is null. This will filter out Cases which don't have Accounts.

```
List<Case> caseList = [
    SELECT Id, ContactId, AccountId, Account.Name 
    FROM Case 
    WHERE AccountId != NULL
        AND (
            RecordType.Name = 'Support Case' OR 
            RecordType.Name = 'CAE Support Case' OR
            RecordType.Name = 'L2 Case' OR 
            RecordType.Name = 'Atmel Classic'
        )
];
```

Now you can either

add the results to a Set so that duplicate Accounts returned are discarded.

OR

add a GROUP BY option.
i.e.

```
AggregateResult[] aggregateCaseList = [
    SELECT AccountId, Account.Name 
    FROM Case 
    WHERE AccountId != NULL 
        AND (
            RecordType.Name = 'Support Case' OR 
            RecordType.Name = 'CAE Support Case' OR
            RecordType.Name = 'L2 Case' OR 
            RecordType.Name = 'Atmel Classic'
        )
    GROUP BY AccountId, Account.Name
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write complicated code to manage this. As I understand, you need to display all the accounts which have related cases. You can use the below code to implement this.

```
Map<Id, String> accountsMap = new Map<Id, String>();
for(Case c :[SELECT Id, ContactId, AccountId, Account.Name 
            FROM Case 
            WHERE (RecordType.Name = 'Support Case' 
                OR RecordType.Name = 'CAE Support Case' 
                OR RecordType.Name = 'L2 Case' 
                OR RecordType.Name = 'Atmel Classic')]){
    accountsMap.put(c.AccountId, c.Account.Name);    
}

System.debug('Accounts with cases '+accountsMap.values());
```

If you need only `Account.Name` field, then just use `Set<String>` and add Account.Name to that set not needed Map.

Comment: I think you lost track halfway through your answer. Your first sentence says `I understand, you need to display all the accounts which don't have related cases.` And your debug statement says the exact opposite: `System.debug('Accounts with cases '+accountsMap.values());` I don't think this will actually help the OP

Comment: @gNerb Thanks for pointing out that. Corrected that part.

Answer (score 1):

As you've seen, there are several ways to approach this type of query. Based on your stated objective, I would generally opt for the [semi-join or anti-join](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm#semijoin_and_antijoin) query strategy to query for the Accounts in which you are interested directly - i.e., those that have Cases.

```
 SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Case)
```

Note regarding limits that

> There is no limit on the number of records matched in a subquery. Standard SOQL query limits apply to the main query.

So this query will return to you up to 50,000 Accounts which do not have Cases, regardless of the number of Cases you match in the subquery.

Comment: That's good to know that there are no row limits, but that doesn't necessarily speak to the queries performance. I'm very much not a database expert. Does this query perform efficiently enough on large data sets compared to the alternative answers?

Comment: I would expect that this would run faster. It touches and returns less data to the client over the whole process (subset of Accounts only versus all qualifying Cases + subset of Accounts when later queried), and I think it's more likely to be selective. Additionally, foreign keys (lookup fields) are always indexed. Data volume is going to be a consideration with any query strategy the OP adopts (are there > 50k responsive Accounts? Is there massive parent-child data skew?), however.

Comment: That said, predicting query performance has a lot of complexity to it and I'm open to correction!

Answer (score 1):

I think that your issue is probably best solved with a slight architectural change. Add a field that counts the number of cases on the account. I'm not certain but I believe you cannot create a roll-up from one standard object to another so you may need a something like [DLRS](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries/wiki/Getting-Started-With-DLRS) or [LREngine](https://github.com/abhinavguptas/Salesforce-Lookup-Rollup-Summaries) (It's possible to achieve a roll-up field with a PB but it requires some creative math and has some issues when updating records that were created before the PB was created so **a pb would only be recommended if you didn't have a dev**, which you obviously do).

Once you have this field, you're query is super easy:

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE NumberOfCases__c > 0
```

This also allows for creating reports (yay!) or dashboards (even more yay!). Depending on your use case this could completely erase your need for the code you're writing.

### Batch Processes

What ever you're trying to do could be put into a [batch process](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm).

Batch processes allow you to provide a query that returns records and then operates on them in "chunks". This means it doesn't matter how many rows your query returns you'll be able to operate on them all. Batch processes also have higher resource limits as they are executed when the resources are available as opposed to immediately executing.

### Standard Set Controller

You may consider using getting tricky with [standard set controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm) as well.

**Disclaimer**: I'm just bored enough and decided to see what other options I could come up with. This answer provides an alternative that other contributors haven't put forward yet. While it will work, there are reasons you may or may not want to implement it and this should be considered thoroughly (this post intentionally does not have copy-pasta).

### Visualforce

The standard set controller exists primarily for VF pages as there are view state limits and limits on iteration components preventing displaying more than 1k records in a table for instance. Using the standard set controller allows for returning a subset of records and provides an easy way to navigate from page to page.

### Not Visualforce

You can create a controller even if you're not actually in a VF page. The controller automatically paginates data and lets you work on the subset before moving to the next page (As I'm writing this I realize you could even use this in a batch process to operate on a set of records at a time although I'm really not sure why you'd be crazy enough to try this :)). This means at the very least you'll never get the too many row limit for a single query (although you could still easily hit other limits as you'd still be doing your work inside of a loop. **I'd only recommend this approach if you are really trying to push SF to the very brinks of it's limits**).

Answer (score 0):

> You are doing a query inside for loop, that is causing the error. You
>   can query maximum 50000 rows at once. You should always avoid querying inside for loop.

I have just removed the inside query and make it outside. Also, nested for loop is not advisable. it can exceed CPU time limit.

Also, You don't need to do the same query two times. You can use Listname.Size() method.

```
Integer OffSt = 0;
Integer lmt = 40000;
Set<Id> stContactIds = new Set<Id>();

List<Case> caselist=    [SELECT Id,ContactId,AccountId FROM Case WHERE 
        (RecordType.Name = 'Support Case' OR RecordType.Name = 'CAE Support Case' 
        OR RecordType.Name = 'L2 Case' OR RecordType.Name = 'Atmel Classic')];
if(caselist.Size()> 0){

        for(Case cas :caselist)
        {
            stContactIds.add(cas.AccountId); 
        }
    }
```